# How to update rows with the value from other rows that have the same foreign key

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-update, foreign-keys

Thanks in advance! This is what I have:

```
primary_key | foreign_key   | field_to_update
---------------------------------------------
          1 |             1 |              A 
          2 |             1 |              - 
          3 |             2 |              B
          4 |             2 |              -
---------------------------------------------
```

Expected results:

```
primary_key | foreign_key   | field_to_update
---------------------------------------------
          1 |             1 |              A 
          2 |             1 |              A 
          3 |             2 |              B
          4 |             2 |              B
---------------------------------------------
```

How would I proceed? I don't think I can do:

```
UPDATE table
SET field_to_update = field_to_update
WHERE ...
```

That doesn't seem to make sense. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: What is the `-` in the column `field_to_update`? Is it `NULL` or it is actually a `-`?

Comment: @forpas It's an empty value. It's not NULL. It's actually ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update` with `join`:

```
update t join
       (select foreign_key, max(field_to_update) as field_to_update
        from t 
        group by foreign_key
       ) tt
       on t.foreign_key = tt.foreign_key
    set t.field_to_update = tt.field_to_update
    where t.field_to_update is null;
```

Comment: Ok that seems to does it if the foreign key is in t, but I've just realized I forgot to mention... I only obtained the foreign key by joining another table based on the primary key. I think I'll have to create a temporary table first and then your solution will probably work. Thanks.

Comment: @G.Langlois . . . If you have trouble making it work, then ask a *new* question with a more correct description of the tables.